# Create ODBC connection to MariaDB (Localhost)

Tags: odbc, mariadb, dsn

I have set up a webserver (OS Raspbian, Apache, MariaDB) and now I want to read the database into Qlik Sense (on my desktop PC).

If I want to create a new ODBC connection in Windows, I get the following error message:

"[ma-3.1.4] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)"

I am using the "MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver". The specified user has all rights.

Do you have any idea where the error is? I am doing this for the first time. Please let me know if you are missing crucial information.

Greetings

Comment: For code running on your Windows box, `localhost` refers to that Windows machine. However, MariaDB isn't running on your Windows box, it is on another machine (Raspbian), so you need to specify that machine's IP address instead of `localhost`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

That was a problem. I also had to create another user with all rights. I thought the root would work as well.